# Batch rename files; problems with sorting hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, rename, file-rename

I want to rename and add numbers to a bunch of lesson files, which I downloaded from YouTube. They are, however, in the wrong order. I have a list with all the correct names in the order they should be watched.

So my idea is to take that list, make hashes out of them with keys, which will later be used as numbering of the files, and the value will be the actual file name. After that I will sort my hashes for the keys and iterate through my directory and rename all the files included in the directory.

I have the following code right now:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/ruby
 2 
 3 counter = 0
 4 
 5 folder_path = "SOME_PATH"
 6 names = Hash.new
 7 
 8 file = File.new("names.txt", "r")
 9 while (line = file.gets)
10     #puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
11     names[sprintf '%03d', counter] = line
12     counter += 1
13 end
14 file.close
15 
16 puts "======== Names before sorting: \n ========"
17 puts names
18 
19 names.keys.sort
20 
21 puts "======== Names after sorting: \n ========"
22 puts names
23 
24 
25 
26 new_filename = ""
27 counter = 0
28 Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").each do |f|
29         #puts "#{counter}: #{File.basename(f, File.extname(f))}"
30         numbering = (sprintf '%03d', counter)
31         new_filename = numbering + " - " + names[numbering]
32 
33         File.rename(f, folder_path + "/" + new_filename + File.extname(f))
34         counter += 1
35 end
36 
37 puts "Renaming complete."
```

The problems are now that my hashes don't really sort. I think it is because my key values are actually string and not numbers, but how else would I achieve leadings zeros for my renaming?

The renaming process itself doesn't quite work either. It seems to work for the first couple videos, but then I get the following error message:

```
main.rb:33:in `rename': No such file or directory - PATH - .mp4 or PATH -  - Dot and Cross Product Comparison/Intuition (Errno::ENOENT)
```

EDIT:

Wow, my bad. I didn't check the names.txt. It actually had a name with a forward slash in it. Thus, causing the above error message.

I did the sorting with 'names.index(names.values.sort[counter])'

Comment: How it possible that this line works - names[sprintf '%03d', counter] = line, why you do have second parameter in square brackets?

Comment: Is that somehow not possible? That's the part where I am assigned the leading zero numbers.

Comment: sorry, it's parameters for sprintf, i didn't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

When you've typed `names.keys` you got an array of keys, not the hash, then sorting it didn't affect your hash. If you want to print hash in sorted way you can do like this:

```
names.keys.sort.map do |key|
  puts "#{key} #{names[key]}"
end
```